# Android SDK Twitter client

Tags: android, api, twitter, sdk

Can anyone direct me to an tutorials which will help me in reading the tweets using android sdk for a  a specific user.

All I want to accomplish is read the tweets and display it preferably using JSON output of tweeter api.

I don't need to post any tweets. I am newbie to sdk. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to the Android platform, this may help get your feet wet as well as accomplishing what you want to do.
[link text](http://sites.google.com/site/appinventor/interacting-with-web-services)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I looked into this...but unfortunate to say I could not get what I was looking for. I am looking to develop an school app in which I need to pull the tweets of this school without giving login details. Can I get a source code for this ...?? thanks again ...!!!